# Local Database in C#, Removing and Adding new column

Tags: c#, sql, sorting, auto-increment, local-database

I'm making a KTV System, and in part of that system I need to have a database where I can add Karaoke Songs, Store, Delete and Access them. I'm using c#, VS2012. Local database for my database, created a table with 5 columns (Code, Title, Artist, Genre, Path).

- **Set my code to be unique key and primary key, and also auto-incremented w/ default values(1,1)**
- **Path Column is for the path of the video file to be played whenever a songs is chosen.**

I didn't program the database functions, just drag and drop the built-in functions from the datasource like this:
[image]

Everything works fine, all the basic functions are working as it should be. When adding it produces negative and weird auto-incremented primary key(which is Code Column) but I know it's fine because everytime I re-run it is already correct. Now

And one thing, after I added my **Data Connection** and **Data Source** I also add a New data connection, connecting into the database that is located in the bin folder of the project. Because if I wont do that, everytime I refresh the database it will erase the data inside of it. Or everytime I close the project, it deletes the data, and it gets data from the Empty database from the Project folder not from the bin.

**PROBLEM:**
For example:
 I tried to add 6 rows and then deleted them all, I was thinking that whenever I will add new rows the Code Column will start from 1 2 and 3 again but not, 7, 8 and 9. It seems like it is skipping because there are already 6 existing columns but **checked** the data table in the database, it isn't. The deleted 6 columns are also gone, same as with the data in the form.
 - **[image: For example:]**

**and something like this also**

[image]

I want the Code Column to be always sorted, if ever I delete or Add new rows into the local database.

Answer (score 0):

It all  depends how you delete your data.

```
DELETE * FROM ...
```

will not affect your auto-increment primary key generator. However,

```
TRUNCATE TABLE ...
```

will reset the counter to its initial seed.

Comment: Sir I didn't program the delete function, It was automatically generated by the data source, when I drag and drop it to the form.

Comment: If you want to retain control of a unique field to identify your songs, create a new column for that purpose and establish a unique index on it. Most likely the control you are using observes some type of data integrity process and will only delete records using the `DELETE` statement. Therefore, you can only accept the fact that your primary keys will always increment. IF you want to create a way to clean the table, add a new button, which will perform the `TRUNCATE` operation. And don't call me Sir. Ever.

Answer (score 0):

May I suggest that you don't attempt to control your auto-generated ID (code), but introduce a new column in your query using the `ROW_NUMBER()` function.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to reset your primary key or code column truncate the table

```
Truncate Table tableName
```

Answer (score 0):

Truncate like others have said will work or with DCBB CHECKIDENT:

```
DBCC CHECKIDENT (TABLENAMEHERE, RESEED, 0)
```